# Computer Vision

Tags: computer-vision, text-extraction

I am new to computer vision. I am trying to extract text from video frames and images. Most of the codes provided in github are compatible with python <3 versions. Any idea on how to proceed and get the related codes and good papers.

Note: I have already implemented pytesseract-OCR and I haven't gotten good result.

[From this image, I have to extract acer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xvrm.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm afraid your question is very broad at the moment, and you also have combine a dozen questions inside one. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Although it is an annoying read, it contains sound advice. Also note that questions that ask for library recommendations are considered off-topic and are likely to be closed.

Comment: And welcome to upvote levels by the way ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello TISHANT CHANDRAKAR.

At first, you must understand how text recognizer works.

```
1. have-text-region is extracted from the image
2. we recognize text for each region
3. Combine the text of all regions to form final result
```

Tesseract itself work very well for step 2. But for step 1, it only work well with text in document. In computer vision, step 1 is called "Scene text detection". So your next step is find some good code, or paper which could do "scene text detection".

If you want to learn and read paper there is a list here [Scene text detection list](https://github.com/chongyangtao/Awesome-Scene-Text-Recognition) . But in my opinion, the text in you image is white text on black background so a simple color threshold could solve step 1 easily.

Hope that help

Answer (score 0):

There are many repositories out there for text detection&recognition, the tesseract is not a bad one but you need to configure it correctly like identifying oem, psm params follow the link below for more best practice

https://ai-facets.org/tesseract-ocr-best-practices/

On your example image, what matter is text detection and pre-processing steps, like deskew correction, you can check OpenCV examples